# How to Visually divide the grid using Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

When Expression Blend is there, I hate coding myself for grid division etc. How it's possible to do that visually? I could not see that neither on properties nor with any menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below link, there is good tutorial to do that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294491.aspx